# ParseUser.getDate("createdAt") is always null

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am running the following code below I get valid values for all other fields but not for the date why is that? The date is always null. I tried with both createdAt and updatedAt null for all results. Is there any reason why I am always getting null? Even though I am getting accurate values for the other fields?

```
String fbId = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("fbId");
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("facebookId", fbId);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> users, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    ParseUser user = users.get(0);
                    bioText.setText(user.getString("aboutBio"));
                    collegeText.setText(user.getString("aboutCollege"));
                    degreeText.setText(user.getString("aboutDegree"));
                    Date lastActive =  (Date) user.getDate("createdAt");
                    Log.d("", "date is " +lastActive);
                    Calendar myCal = new GregorianCalendar();
                    myCal.setTime(lastActive);
                    lastPing.setText("skewp"+ myCal.getTimeInMillis());



                } else {
                }
            }
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parse has a built in method for getting the createdAt and updatedAt fields.

```
ParseUser.getCreatedAt(); 
ParseUser.getUpdatedAt();
```

Use those instead of using "createdAt" and "updatedAt" as keys